# Meteor Blaze: Access UI.contentBlock from template helper

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Is it possible to access `UI.contentBlock` from within a template helper?

For instance, given the following template:

```
<template name="select">
  <ul class="select">
    {{optionsToListElements}}
  </ul>
  <select>
    {{> UI.contentBlock}}
  </select>
</template>
```

Is there any way to pass UI.contentBlock into the template helper `optionsToListElements`? I've tried passing it directly as in `{{optionsToListElements UI.contentBlock}}` and as a named variable, `{{optionsToListElements contentBlock=UI.contentBlock}}`, and just trying to access it from the helper without passing it at all, but none of those seems to work.

Comment: After reading the docs on `UI.contentBlock` I realized I was way off so I removed my answer.

Comment: @Michel Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access the content block inside the helper using Template.instance().$('select')

Comment: This is the best solution I've seen so far. I was hoping for a way to access the content block before the template was rendered, but it seems like that's not possible.